# To find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers

Tags: python

```
def largest_palindrome(n1,n2):
    mylist = [x for x in range(n1,n2)]
    for y in mylist:
        if y == y[::-1]:
            print(y)
        else:
            pass
```

largest_palindrome(100,9801)

When I am executing this code the error that comes up is **TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable**.
I need to know what is the problem is in this code and what changes will be done to make this code running.

Comment: Your code doesn't match the title. Assuming you fix, so `y` is a str, you are still just finding the largest palindrome in range(n1, n2). Where is the product of 2 digit numbers supposed to come into it?

Answer (score 5):

You need to cast to string to be able to reverse and compare:

```
def largest_palindrome():                        # <-- arguments are not needed
    for y in (x for x in range(9801, 100, -1)):  # use a generator, that iterates from largest to smallest. 
        if str(y) == str(y)[::-1]:
            return y                             # early exit when largest match is found (it will be the first)

print(largest_palindrome())
```

#### spoiler alert:

```
9779
```

#### as a one liner:

```
max([x for x in range(9801, 100, -1) if str(x) == str(x)[::-1]])
```

#### As a one liner generator

(thanks @Austin in the comments):

```
next(x for x in range(9801, 100, -1) if str(x) == str(x)[::-1])
```

Comment: also, just iterate in reverse, that way the first one you encounter would be the largest!

Comment: You still generate the whole list which is inefficient

Comment: Yes, Thank you! I changed to a generator in order to avoid creating the entire list.

Comment: Instead of `max`, I would prefer a `next` on generator like: `next(x for x in range(9801, 100, -1) if str(x) == str(x)[::-1])`.

Comment: Thanks man the code of yours solved my problem.Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Or even `...for x in map(str, range(9801, 100, -1))...`.

Answer (score 1):

Reblochon's answer doesn't solve the problem as it only iterates between the smallest and the biggest number that could come from two two-digit numbers. It doesn,t iterate through two-digit numbers.

```
def largest_palindrome():
    lastBiggestProduct = 0;
    lastBiggestNumb = 10;
    for firstNum in range(10,100):
        a = list(range(lastBiggestNumb,firstNum))
        a.extend(range(firstNum+1,100))
        for secondNum in a:
            prod = firstNum*secondNum
            if(prod>lastBiggestProduct and str(prod) == str(prod)[::-1]):
                lastBiggestProduct = firstNum*secondNum
                lastBiggestNumb = secondNum
    return lastBiggestProduct


print(largest_palindrome())
```

**That returns:**

```
9009
```

Comment: Instead of implementing `max` yourself, try to figure a way to use the builtin one. `from itertools import product; max(x*y for x, y in product(range(10, 100), repeat=2) if str(x*y)==str(x*y)[::-1])`

Comment: John La Rooy Your answer is great too, and a great implementation of "itertools" (it's probably faster too)

Comment: Actually, I was being lazy using `product` here - It's more efficient to trim the inner range - `max(x*y for x in range(10, 100) for y in range(x, 100) if str(x*y)==str(x*y)[::-1])`.This reduces the tests by half.  I think it's possibly clearer too. Either way it's still `O(n^2)`